I can't install packages from Git
I'm working on a face recognition project. But when I just wanted to install pip install pip install git+https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition_models, when I write it to cmd I got this error:
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 3 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
  error: 7500 bytes of body are still expected
  fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
  fatal: early EOF
  fatal: index-pack failed
  fatal: could not fetch d4a2c4405ec2e962c521a13af91bf5f7098a62a8 from promisor remote
  warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
  You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
  and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition_models 'C:\Users\kocta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-j6wwwvuo' did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 128
  ╰─> See above for output.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition_models 'C:\Users\kocta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-j6wwwvuo' did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 128
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

I'm using Windows 10 and Python 3.13.0.
How can I avoid this error?

Can you please provide the full call you're making? Are you really using triple quotes somewhere? Or is that just an attempt to format things for display here? Does the same thing happen with other packages as well?

The setup.py file for that project only claims support up to Python 3.6. This may or may not be compatible with more recent pythons, although the error you're getting doesn't seem related to the Python version.

And your pip install command works for me. My advice would be simply to try it again, just like @Tanmay said in their answer.

Can't reproduce this either, running Python 3.12/Ubuntu/AMD64. I'd also check the bug tracker of that project, maybe it's something already known.

The error originates from here:
  fatal: could not fetch d4a2c4405ec2e962c521a13af91bf5f7098a62a8 from promisor remote
  warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.

You managed to clone the repository, but you tried to install a revision/commit that does not exist. You should ensure that the commit you are trying to install exists.
If you did not specify a commit to install then it suggests something is wrong with the repository. Or it could suggest that the owner of the repository yanked a commit on the main/master branch (or maybe they did a rebase), and you were unlucky enough to have tried to install while this was happening.
As an alternative, you can try to separate out the "git clone", checkout and install processes. For example:
git clone https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition_models
cd face_recognition_models
git checkout master # or whatever commit you're interested in
                    # ^-- this is the step that failed last time
cd -
pip install ./face_recognition_models


It seems like there was an interruption while loading the files. You can retry by connecting to different network. This might solve your issue. After connecting to  another network retry using the command
pip install git+https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition_models


That's the same command, isn't it? So you suggest to simply retry the command, not use a different command?

Why connect to a different network? What does that even mean?
